# Generating protected classes with XSD.exe from schema file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, code-generation, xsd.exe

I'm currently using XSD.exe to generate classes for my xsd schema file using the following command:

```
xsd.exe MySchema.xsd /classes /namespace:MyNamespace
```

I'd like to be able to have the tool output internal classes instead of the public classes is creates by default. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible Lead for you in another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435524/is-there-a-way-to-get-xsd-exe-to-generate-classes-with-internal-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [xsd2code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) instead, you can tune it as you wish.

Comment: Unfortunately, using xsd.exe is a requirement for this project. That tool does look a lot more versatile though, I'll keep it in mind for future projects.